# Search LinkedIn profiles of employees and return top URL programatically

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, linkedin-api

We want to create a program or script that will search LinkedIn with the firstname, lastname, company and title, of our company's internal employees and pull the search results into a file or table.

Based on LinkedIn keywords, I can the generate search URL as:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3Ajohn%20AND%20lastname%3Adoe%20AND%20company%3Amicrosoft%20AND%20title%3Aceo&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER
```

I need to pull or scrape the top URL from results. I can sign in using my account in the browser.

I don't know if LinkedIn exposes an API, or if I can do this with *curl*, or what language would be best suited for this.. Anyone have a simple, sample code to start with ?

Answer (score 2):

As you need to be signed in during the whole scraping process, your best choice for crawling the website would be to use [Selenuim](http://www.seleniumhq.org). The same can be achieved through [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/), but Selenium is a much better choice.

For the scraping part, you should stick with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Selenium requires a webdriver for launching the browser. For this, you have three options:

- [geckdriver](http://geckodriver)
- [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)

Personally, I would always prefer PhantomJS as it provides [headless browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) which is ideal if you want to extend your script to a separate website etc.

Here is a minimal script launching a chrome browser through Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3Ajohn%20AND%20lastname%3Adoe%20AND%20company%3Amicrosoft%20AND%20title%3Aceo&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER'

chromedriver = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(base_url)

# sign in and perform all your scraping
```

Note: I don't think LinkedIn exposes an API for searching their content, so you have to stick with what I mentioned above.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I can be signed in using my own account.. Also, would u be able to give a simple code to achieve this.. pseudo-code here :
data = soup.pullUrl('http://linkedin.com/search...')

Comment: You can download the chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).